# Replace macro with constexpr function to define enum

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, macros

I have a macro such as

`#define ascii_to_3bit(c) c & 0x60 - 1`

I have tried to replace it with this:

```
constexpr const std::uint8_t ascii_to_3bit(char c)
{
    return c & 0x60 - 1;
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
enum class Column
{
    A = ascii_to_3bit('a'),
    B = ascii_to_3bit('b'),
    C = ascii_to_3bit('c'),
    D = ascii_to_3bit('d'),
    E = ascii_to_3bit('e'),
    F = ascii_to_3bit('f'),
    G = ascii_to_3bit('g'),
    H = ascii_to_3bit('h')
};
```

It works fine as a macro but dies with "function call must have a constant value with a constant expression" when it is a function.

Is it possible? Compiler is whatever VS2015 ships.

Comment: [Works when I fix the name](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48839fd445f285aa).

Comment: Did you drop the `lower` in the name on purpose?

Comment: Sorry about name discrepency. It seems Clang has better support for this than MSVC++ (big no brainer there) if that compiles.

Comment: [This site](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) uses MSVC 14 and it compiles on there. Basic `constexpr` support was added in this latest release. Perhaps the toolchain is set to something else in your settings.

Comment: Works for me, using g++ 4.8.4, when I drop the `const` after `constexpr`.